# Struts: Reference a Form-Bean as a Variable in Common JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1

I have a common JSP included in other pages; it must generically display a certain list from a bean.

All the main JSPs use a certain subclass of that bean.

In struts-config.xml, let's say there is one specific definition for my Action Form bean as an example,

```
<form-bean name="rr5YearBudgetForm"  type="myapp.form.My5YearBudgetActionForm" />
```

The common JSP needs to check properties of that bean, in a general way (with the bean I pass in); these are properties which all the form beans will support. Right now, it's hard-coded to use the specific Form Bean below, but it must work with any bean that's passed in.

```
 <c:if 
            test="${rr5YearBudgetForm.saved == true || fn:length(rr5YearBudgetForm.budgetPeriods) > 1}">
```

The question is, how do I pass in a specific variable containing my form-bean? I tried this simple c:set var, but that defines a string, with no properties.

**Calling JSP**

```
<c:set var="budgetForm" value="rr5YearBudgetForm" scope="request" />    
<%@ include file="common.jsp" %>
```

**Common JSP**

```
<c:if test="${budgetForm.saved == true || fn:length(budgetForm.budgetPeriods) > 1}">
```

but that does not work. I need a way to pass in the actual bean rather than a string.

Comment: Which Struts version is this ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios Struts 1.3

Comment: Then why did you tag it as Struts2 ?

Comment: My mistake. It's no longer tagged as Struts 2. Someone changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the bean tag:

```
<s:bean name="com.mkyong.common.action.HelloBean" var="hello">
  <s:param name="msg">Hello Bean Tag</s:param>
</s:bean>
```

This tag library contains tags useful in accessing beans and their properties, as well as defining new beans (based on these accesses) that are accessible to the remainder of the page via scripting variables and page scope attributes.

Comment: Is this tag part of Struts? Or where I can get this library?

Comment: Yes - http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#struts-bean.tld

Comment: There is no "bean" tag in that library as in your example. There are tags "define", "write", etc. Are you pulling it from a different library?

Comment: Either use : bean (struts-bean.tld) - uri: http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean or use  <jsp:useBean id="sampleBean" class="com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.SampleBean" scope="session">...either of them should work